# Joining two tables via a third mapping table in BigQuery / SQL

Tags: sql, join

I was wondering if you could help me. I'd like to select a number of columns from table1 and merge them with some columns from table 2, using table 3 which maps the customer_id to cust_num.

Table 1

| customer_id | account | balance | account_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 100 | A |
| 2 | B | 200 | B |
| 3 | C | 300 | B |

Table 2

| cust_num | score1 | score2 | score3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
| 2345 | 20 | 200 | 2000 |
| 3456 | 30 | 300 | 3000 |

Table 3

| cust_id | ref |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 |
| 2345 | 2 |
| 3456 | 3 |

In table 3 ref= table 1's customer_id and cust_id = table 2's "cust_num". I can't change any of the variable or column names.

Ideally I would like to select account and balance from table 1 and match them with score 1 and score 2 from table 2 to end up with

| cust_num | account | balance | score1 | score2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | A | 100 | 10 | 100 |
| 2345 | B | 200 | 20 | 200 |
| 34567 | C | 300 | 30 | 300 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use join

```
SELECT t3.cust_id,t1.account,t1.balance,t3.score1,t3.score2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table3 t2 ON t1.customer_id = t2.ref
JOIN table2 t3 ON t2.cust_id = t3.cust_num
```